# Flatten distinct in apache pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
DUMP A;
(10000,({(10000),(20000),(50000)},{(10000),(20000),(30000)}))
(20000,({(10000),(20000),(50000)},{(20000)},{(10000),(20000),(30000)}))
(30000,({(30000)},{(10000),(20000),(30000)}))
(40000,({(40000)},{(40000),(50000)}))
(50000,({(40000),(50000)},{(10000),(20000),(50000)}))
DESCRIBE A;
{foo: bytearray, bar_gp: (baz: {(foo: bytearray)})}
```

I eventually want it to look like this:

```
DUMP A;
(10000,{(10000),(20000),(50000),(30000)})
(20000,{(10000),(20000),(50000),(30000)})
(30000,{(10000),(20000),(30000)})
(40000,{(40000),(50000)})
(50000,{(40000),(50000),(10000),(20000)})
```

If I tried using:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0, FLATTEN($1);
C = FOREACH B {D = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN($1); D= DISTINCT D; GENERATE $0, D; }
```

but I kept getting the error:

```
expression is not a project expression: (Name: ScalarExpression) Type: null Uid: null)
```

How can I get the desired output? I know I could use a UDF to parse it, but I would like to find a built-in solution.

Comment: Can you DESCRIBE A and add the schema details ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do distinct on the BAG before flattening it.

```
B = FOREACH A {
   D = DISTINCT $1;
   GENERATE $0, FLATTEN(D)}
```

Comment: The problem is that the elements of the bags (the tuples) are already distinct, so the above just returns the same as my definition of B, above.